# Android custom digital clock, error running while loop "Unhandled exception type InterruptedException"

Tags: java, android, loops

I'm building a simple `clock` on android.

My problem is on the while loop, when I use `Thread.sleep(5000)` I get error:  "`Unhandled exception type InterruptedException`".

How should I run the loop so it works correctly? There aren't too many lines of code so I copied it entirely, hopefully will be useful for somebody since I haven't been able to find many examples of clocks.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    TextView hours;
    TextView minutes;
    Calendar c;
    int cur_hours;
    int cur_minutes;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.clock_home);
        hours = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.hours);
        minutes = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.minutes);
        while (true) {
            updateTime();
            Thread.sleep(5 * 1000); // Unhandled exception type InterruptedException
            }
        }

    public void updateTime() {
        c = Calendar.getInstance();
        hours.setText("" + c.get(Calendar.HOUR));
        minutes.setText("" + c.get(Calendar.MINUTE));
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Thread.sleep](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#sleep%28long%29) throws InterruptedException, you need to either catch (or) rethrow.

Wrap Thread.sleep call inside `try/catch`

Example:

```
try
{
Thread.sleep(5 * 1000);
}catch(InterruptedException ie)
{
 //Log message if required.
}
```

EDIT:

As [InterruptedException javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/InterruptedException.html)

> Thrown when a thread is waiting, sleeping, or otherwise paused for a
>   long time and another thread interrupts it using the interrupt method
>   in class Thread

Comment: In what circumstances will that exception be thrown?

Comment: Thanks, I figured about as much. The OP's design is obviously flawed, but I didn't have a solution at the moment to comment.

Comment: @JonathonReinhart: I see what you mean, agree. OP, if you are looking for simple clock, I think there are examples available on internet it is better to use them instead re-engineering. http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-analogclock-and-digitalclock-example/

Comment: I have only found examples of the digitalClock and textClock views provided by the sdk. But they are hard to customize. updateTime() works I just don't know how to run it once a couple of seconds. Do you have any ideas?